# Passing CallerID for PSTN in From Header using JSSIP

Tags: webrtc, sip, freeswitch, jssip

I'm using JsSIP to connect to FreeSwitch and then to the PSTN. I'm looking to pass the callerID in the From header. I have my code set up somewhat like this:

```
var TheCallerIDTest = '+33...number in E164 format';
var TheSipClient = new JsSIP.UA({....}); //works fine

var TheHandlers = {

    'sending': function (e) {

        var TheSipURI = new JsSIP.URI('sip', TheCallerIDTest, 'MyFreeswitchServerUrl', 5060, null, null);
        var TheHeader = new JsSIP.NameAddrHeader(TheSipURI, '', null);

        //displays the correct From header just fine
        console.log(TheHeader);

        //here's where I want to modify the INVITE request
        e.from = TheHeader; 
    },
}

var TheCallOptions = {

    'eventHandlers': TheHandlers,
    'mediaConstraints': { 'audio': true, 'video': false }
};

function TestCall() {

    TheSipClient.start();

    TheSipClient.call("+33...E164 number", TheCallOptions);
}
```

Looking at the documentation, https://jssip.net/documentation/3.3.x/api/session/#event_sending, I'm hoping the add a `JsSIP.NameAddrHeader` to the 'from' header of the `JsSIP.OutgoingRequest INVITE` request. The console output logs the correct From header I want to add.

However, when I look at the `JsSIP:RTCSession emit "sending" [request:InitialOutgoingInviteRequest` console log, it's not showing the header I want to add, and the From header that's received on the server is not the one I want to send.

What do I need to change in my code to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do like this:

```
e.request.headers.From[0] = TheHeader;
```

Also probably this make sense to remove some other headers you do not want to send.

Answer (score 0):

Latest version [3.10.x](https://jssip.net/documentation/3.10.x/api/ua/#method_call) of JsSIP supports setting from and display name in the ua call options itself.

`ua.call('sip:bob@example.com', {fromUserName:"<caller id>"});`